# How to tell if any tests failed from result of testthat::test_dir

Tags: r, testing, testthat

I have a small testing program that uses `testthat`

```
library(testthat)
source("src/MyFile.r")
results <- test_dir("tests", reporter="summary")
```

So, I am running this via `Rscript`. The problem is that the exit code is always 0 even when there were test failures. So, I want to call `stop` if there are any failures. But I can't seem to get the right bit of code to do that. Is there a method or field in `results` that I should be looking at to determine if there were any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, my solution is iterating through the results like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(results)) {
  if (!is(results[[i]]$result[[1]], "expectation_success")) {
    stop("There were test failures")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also tweak jamesatha's answer to retrieve the number of test failures.

```
failed.tests <- sapply(results, function(r) {
  !is(r$result[[1]], "expectation_success")
})
```

You then allows you to fail, as before:

```
if (any(failed.tests)) {
  stop("There were test failures")
}
```

or do something more bespoke like

```
if (any(failed.tests)) {
  failed.test.count <- length(which(failed.tests))
  stop(paste(failed.test.count,"failed tests is",failed.test.count,"too many!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `stop_on_failure=TRUE` in as a parameter to `test_dir`. If you get any test failures it will raise an error and exit non zero.

e.g:

```
results <- test_dir("mypath", stop_on_failure=TRUE)
```

This is documented [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/testthat/versions/2.1.1/topics/test_dir)